# Gonna need a calculator

Tags: rebus

What am I going to be doing with this?

[image]

Hint:

> You don’t need a hint, look at the title

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are going to

> Crunch some numbers.

Explanation

> The numbers are printed on top of a cereal that looks like Cap'n Crunch's Peanut Butter Crunch.

Title

> You use a calculator to crunch numbers i.e. do some calculations.

Comment: Correct! Well done!

Comment: @RohitJose if this answer is correct, I believe it would be better if the puzzle included the `knowledge` tag with regards to the explanation section. Apart from that, nice puzzle! DVL19 $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :D